# WPF xmlns:local="clr-namespace:

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am having problems with Namespaces, I seem to be chasing the error around and now I am down to one left that I don't understand.  All my files have the same namespace, I don't really think I need more then one for a small program.

```
Example.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Example"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:chart="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chart"
         xmlns:chartView="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.ChartView;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.Chart"
         xmlns:telerikQuickStart="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls.QuickStart;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example.ExampleViewModel"
         xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
<telerikQuickStart:QuickStart.ExampleHeader>
    <TextBlock Text="Atlanta Sales Dashboard" Margin="8" />
</telerikQuickStart:QuickStart.ExampleHeader>
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:ExampleViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext> /


ExampleViewModel.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls;
using Telerik.Windows.Controls.Map;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Resources;
using System.Xml;



namespace Example.ExampleViewModel
{
public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase
```

The ExampleViewModel is still giving me the following errors.

```
 Error  1   The name "ExampleViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Example.ExampleViewModel".   D:\visual studio 12\Projects\Map1\Map1\Example.xaml 14  9   Map1
    Error   2   The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'Example'  D:\visual studio 12\Projects\Map1\Map1\obj\x86\Debug\Example.g.cs   62  22  Map1
```

Comment: Is `Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard.Example` really the local namespace (i.e. in the same assembly as the above XAML)?

Comment: Yes, This is the Default Namespace for the application in the project properties.  Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard

Comment: What namespace is the `ExampleViewModel` class in?

Comment: namespace Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard

Comment: Your `x:Class` namespace looks incorrect. Is the XAML located in a class called `Example`?

Comment: Your `local` namespace is wrong then. Remove the `Example` portion at the end. It should point to the namespace containing the `ExampleViewModel` class.

Comment: Yes the name of the .xaml is Example.xaml

Comment: Error 1 The name "ExampleViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard". D:\visual studio 12\Projects\Map1\Map1\Example.xaml 14 9 Map1

Comment: Do I really need xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard.Example"

Comment: This is the first couple of lines in ExampleViewModel--->namespace Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard
{
    public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching this out I finally cleaned that error out with the help from the following: http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=31429

But this moved me to another error that i am going to contact Telerik on.  It seems they are using a control which is in another namespace.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please review all of your namespaces. Some of them appear to be incorrect. Ensure that all of the classes you intend to reference have the correct namespace (including assembly) defined.

I suggest you start with only a few namespaces, ensure that they work without error, and then gradually add all of the required namespaces.

Comment: There should be only one Name space, I will copy the default and try pasting it into all of the files.

Comment: No difference same error -->Error 1 The name "ExampleViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard". D:\visual studio 12\Projects\Map1\Map1\Example.xaml 14 9 Map1

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an error in the xaml definition, see:

the control class is:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard.Example"
```

but you are defining the "local" namesapce exactly with the same name:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard.Example
```

i think there should be an error in your xaml, or in your class definitions, try this...

Comment: I have posted the two errors:-->Error 1 The name "ExampleViewModel" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map.SalesDashboard". D:\visual studio 12\Projects\Map1\Map1\Example.xaml 14 9 Map1
-->Error 2 The namespace 'Telerik.Windows.Examples.Map' already contains a definition for 'SalesDashboard' D:\visual studio 12\Projects\Map1\Map1\obj\x86\Debug\Example.g.cs 63 26 Map1
I don't know what to do with 2 since it is in the code that is generated

Comment: I only think that is odd that a class have the same name of a namespace. Try renaming the class